# Extra power through USB3 to make a thunderbolt powered USB switch work better

Tags: usb, power-supply, usb-3, thunderbolt, usb-c

I have a usb-c thunderbolt HuB that has a HDMI output, a VGA output, 3 USB3 ports, an ethernet one and it has to be connected to a power adapter and to the laptop. I'm suspecting that the power in is not enough to make it correctly work because, if I add more USB ports, everything becomes slow, or packets (like mouse actions) get lost.

My laptop has another thunderbolt usb-c port. Do you think that is possible to connect this port to the Hub via the USB3 port and make it work in some way better?

[EDIT]
I wrote switch, but I meant the USB HUB

The hub is powered via the cable of my laptop inserted into the Hub usb-c thunderbolt port. The hub is then plugged in with is small cable into my usb-c thunderbolt port.

The hub is this one: https://www.amazon.it/gp/product/B07V9R5F8B/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1H8LO7P3JU1ID&psc=1

> Which hub are you using? Why not plug some of the devices into the
>   other USB-C port?

In the other port there is already the mouse bluetooth adapter because with that hub it does not work better.. and I need this hub to transfer data as well

I was thinking to buy a Usb3 type A to USB3 type A cable, and to plug it into the Usb hub and my pc (via a USB3 to USB-c adapter that I already have)

Comment: Detail is needed: "Do you think that is possible to connect this port to the switch..." What switch? Is the hub power adapter plugged in? Which hub are you using? Why not plug some of the devices into the other USB-C port?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'll write more info, thank you for your feedback

Comment: "The hub is powered via the cable of my laptop inserted into the Hub usb-c thunderbolt port. The hub is then plugged in with is small cable into my usb-c thunderbolt port." - could you clarify? How many cables do you use to connect the dock to your laptop?

Comment: Only one the one that was included in the HUB. I clarify it: the laptop cable it usually connects power to the laptop (via USB-c thunderbolt  port). In my current case I'm connecting this cable to the USB hub and the USB Hub has a very small cable that has to be conencted to the USB-C thunderbolt port of  the laptop.. it's like if I'm putting a device in the middle between power and laptop.

Comment: What is the model of laptop?  Connecting the dock by two cables to the host computer is not likely to add more power or bandwidth.  Using a USB-A to USB-A cable is just likely to damage something.

Comment: It is a HP Spectre. I just bought a new one that works without issues